# Find the number of distinct complex values that $P(x) =x^6+2x^5+5x^4+4x^3+6x^2+5x+7$ if $x$ is a solution of $x^3+x+1=0$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

> Let $n$ be the number of distinct complex values which the polynomial function $P(x) =x^6+2x^5+5x^4+4x^3+6x^2+5x+7$ takes, if $x$ is a solution of $x^3+x+1=0$. Find $n$.

I am a bit confused by this problem because what value I get for $n$ is different than what the workbook offers as a result.

If $x$ is a solution of $x^3+x+1=0$, then there is one real solution $x_1$ and two complex, conjugate solution $x_2$, $x_3$ (this can be proven by differentiating $f(x)=x^3+x+1$ once and proving $f$ crosses $OX$ once). Following this line of thought, there must be at least two complex values that $P(x)$ takes, as for $x_1$ it will be a real number and for $x_2$ or $x_3$ the value should be strictly complex (that is, with a term that contains $i$), both "outputs" being complex values (although one is real, because $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$), thus $n\geq 2$. Going further isn't necessary because the book says $n=1$, so there's only one complex value $P(x)$ takes using the solutions of $x^3+x+1=0$. How is that possible? Do you think by "distinct complex values" they mean purely complex numbers and not real ones? Or is perhaps my logic faulty?

Also, tangentially related, if a polynomial has **real** coefficients, do complex, conjugated numbers return the same value? Or can $z$ and $\bar z$ return different values?

Comment: If $p(z)=z$ then $p(i)\neq p(-i)$.

Comment: I don't see how you showed that $P(x)$ takes more than one value. All you've argued is that it *might* take more than one value.  More work is needed.

Comment: Should add:  the authors aren't writing "complex" to exclude real solutions.  In fact, all "three" values taken by $P(x)$ and the three roots are real (and they coincide).

Comment: @lulu I see. Then I will think more about this problem, seeing that I was working on wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going a bit overkill. I agree that $x^3+x+1 = 0$ has $1$ real and two complex solutions. But, they're not easy to find (you'll need the [Cubic Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula)). Unless you're doing a course that involves this formula (or preparing for a contest that requires it), you're not supposed to use it.

As a general method, when you know the value of a lower-degree polynomial $q(x)$ for some specific $x$, (usually $q(x)$ for these $x$s is zero, like here) and you want to find a higher degree polynomial $p(x)$, your aim should be to form an equation something like this:
$$p(x) = q(x)s(x) + r(x)$$where $r(x)$ is of the minimum possible degree (in other words, just divide $p(x)$ by $q(x)$, $s(x)$ is quotient and $r(x)$ is remainder).

Turns out, here $r(x)$ has a very less degree...

Comment: Indeed, after lulu's comments that my logic is wrong I tried to divide the two polynomials to try and spot something, and it turns out the remainder is $6$, so there's only $1$ value, as the workbook says. Thank you for thoroughly explaining the logic behind such problems!

Comment: by the way, for which course/contest are you using the book?

Comment: I am preparing to enter college (which isn't too different from an outright contest, as it is highly competitive haha) and the University has published a book with math problems on the topics of algebra, analysis, and geometry to help future students prepare, and while it contains the final answers, there are few fully-fledged solutions at the back.

Comment: oh right. So the cubic formula wasn't certainly included. Best wishes to you!

Answer (score 2):

The following is equivalent to the long division, but the calculations may be easier to work out sometimes.

Given that $x$ is a root of $x^3 + x + 1 = 0\,$:

$$
x^3 = -x - 1 \tag{1}
$$

Multiplying $(1)$ by $x\,$:

$$
x^4 = -x^2 - x \tag{2}
$$

Multiplying $(2)$ by $x$ and using $(1)\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
x^5 &= -x^3 - x^2
\\ &= -x^2 + x + 1 \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Multiplying $(3)$ by $x$ and using $(1)$ again:

\begin{align}
x^6 &= -x^3 + x^2 + x
\\ &= x^2 + 2x + 1\tag{4}
\end{align}

Substituting $(1),(2),(3),(4)$ in $P(x)\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
P(x) &= x^6 + 2x^5 + 5x^4 + 4x^3 + 6x^2 + 5x + 7
\\ &= (\bcancel{x^2} + \cancel{2 x} + 1) + 2(-\bcancel{x^2} + \cancel{x} + 1) + 5(-\bcancel{x^2} - \cancel{x})
\\ &\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; + 4(-\cancel{x} - 1) + \bcancel{6 x^2} + \cancel{5 x} + 7
\\ &= 6
\end{align}
$$